# Shouldn't [audio] and [sound] be merged together?

Tags: feature-request, tags

I'm talking about [sound](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound) and [audio](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio) here.

**sound** has the following description:

> Audio (heard) output of a game.

**audio** has this:

> The audio component of a game, representing what the player will hear. Comprised of dialogue, music, and sound effects.

From my point of view, I see them colliding therefore splitting questions of same nature in two separate categories.

Shouldn't these both be [*synonymized*](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tags/sound/synonyms) together?

I see that it requires quite some "achievements" in the field to propose such change. Could someone take the initiative?

Comment: I tried, but for some stupid reason you have to have a score of 5 in the tag and it's not something that is unlocked via the 20k gate. Maybe a diamond moderator can do it.

Comment: I suggested the synonym. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms Of course it's going to take a mod anyways...